# Trouble creating in-editor button in custom control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I used Custom Control class to create a panel that can hold many layers of controls separately, but I needed to add an in-editor usable button like "Add Layer" or "Remove Layer". I looked over default controls and found that [TabControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol) has like two link labels ("Add Tab", "Remove Tab") that actually adds and deletes tabs in real time.

[Tab Control Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o35ya.png)

The problem I got is that I can't find no references to that funcionality of controls, and therefore, can't implement it in my custom control.

I couldn't find my problem in other posted questions and not also in internet. I tried searching in source code of referred controls, but I didn't find a reference.

Thanks in advance and sorry if there are mistakes in my english.

Comment: [Smart Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms171829(v=vs.140)) -> [DesignerVerb Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.designerverb)